# ID od node element differs than innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a weird bug - the HTML of a form is:

```
<form id="formId"></form>
```

but the structure when using document.body.childNodes looks like this:

```
form#[object HTMLInputElement]
```

In this case the `document.getElementById('[object HTMLInputElement]')` works but `document.getElementById('formId')` doesn't. Why is that?

I cannot update the id due to this bug as it always stay `[object HTMLInputElement]`. Any ideas?

Comment: `[object HTMLInputElement]` is a string representation of an input field, not a valid CSS selector

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('formId')`

Comment: @spencer.sm - I wrote that this doesn't work.

Comment: @Luca  This code gets generated by the backend and I cannot update it.